# How to avoid node-express from being blocked by fetch call

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, fetch

I have simulated a time consuming asynchronous operation on the node-express route using `setInterval`. while the `setInterval` was waiting, node-express didn't respond to another client's request.
what can be done to prevent blocking of the route?

This is the simulation I have used:

I opened two clients and tried to send requests from both of the clients at the same time. the test was done on localhost.

I have tested it again and again, and the second client gets the responses from the server only after all ten of the first client request were responded.

**Client:**

```
<button onclick='getManyData()'>Get Data </button>
   
    <script>
        function getManyData(){

            for(let i=0; i<10;i++){
                getData()
            }
        }

        function getData(){
           
            fetch('/api/req1')
            .then(res=>res.json())
            .then(data=>{
               
                console.log(data)
            })

        }
    </script>
```

**Server:**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();


app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('/api/req1', (req, res) => {
    setTimeout(()=>{
        res.send({ ok: true })
    },500)
    
})

app.listen(3000, () => { console.log('listen on port 3000') })
```

This is how it looks on the network:
[image]

**Update:**

I have found that this phenomenon happens only on chrome, but not on firefox (in Firefox, all the requests are answered after approximately 500ms). Any suggestions on why this happens?

Comment: I suspect you may not have the problem you think you have.  There doesn't appear to be any problems with your express code.

Comment: I have tested it again and again, and the second client gets a response from the server only after all ten of the first client request were responded.

Comment: Due to the single threaded nature of nodejs if your endpoint is performing blocking/sync operations then you would see this behavior.  The code you posted is not doing this though so did you actually post your real code?

Comment: Yes, just copy-pasted it

Comment: I think this might be an example of understanding instead of an actual issue. It sounds like you expect calls started later to sometimes finish earlier?  This is not a property of asynchronous code.  In practice things are queued up to execute in order even when executed asynchronously. If all of the requests take the same amount of time to execute its logical that they will mostly return in order. This behavior would be managed by the blackbox code in the VM that schedules the execution of async code.  Keep in mind there is no parallel execution of code in NodeJS. It only has one thread.

Comment: I don't think it is an issue of understanding. when I run the tests... the first client sent 10 requests, and got 10 responses, once every 500ms (approximately). only after 5 seconds all request was received (at about 5 seconds), the second client started to get a response (once every 500ms) .


In the meanwhile, I have found something interesting the phenomena happens only on chrome. on postman and on firefox, everything runs fast (in accordance with the expected behavior of the vent-loop)

Comment: The problem is related to Browsers based on Chromium because it will sometimes not send two identical GET requests to the same host at the same time, but Firefox can handle multiple identical requests to the same host at the same time. So, if you're trying to bypass this browser sequencing, then you can add a query string with some sort of random or always different value in it (such that the GET requests are not the exact same URL).